# Django queryset - Filtering related table objects before aggregation

Tags: python, django, aggregate

Consider this model in Django documentation:
[Aggregation and Avg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation)

There is a queryset like this:

```
Author.objects.annotate(average_rating=Avg('book__rating'))
```

which returns all authors annotated by average rate of all of their books.
What if I want to query authors annotated by average rate of their books which have been published for example in 2016.

Note that I want to get results with as few queries as possible.

Comment: Can you describe the models of `Author` and `Book`?

Comment: They are at the beginning of documentation page that I've referenced in the first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the `Book` model has an attribute `pubdate` which is a `DateField`, you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime

y2016 = datetime(2016,1,1)

Author.objects.filter(book__pubdate__lt=y2016) \
              .annotate(average_rating=Avg('book__rating'))
```

So `book__pubdate__lt` means that you check that the `pubdate` of the `book` is less than (`__lt`) `y2016` (the first of january 2016).

In case the `filter` is applied *before* the `annotate` it will filter the books away which are publised before 2016. Note that authors that have not publised before 2016 will *not* be in the resulting `QuerySet`. But this seems logical (since you can not calculate an average over an empty set).

Comment: Won't that filter only those authors with at least one book before 2016 but still annotate those with the average of **all** their books?

Comment: @schwobaseggl: afaik, it will not. Filters with no books will not be in the result. But based on other queries, it will thus leave out the books that are published before 2016.

Comment: book__pubdate__lt=y2016 only means looking for authors whose books have been published before 2016. it won't filter books by pubdate.

Comment: Based on [these queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) it does.

Comment: @MehdiPourfar: in case the `filter` is *after* the `annotate`, you are right. In case it is before, it works.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I stand corrected. Not entirely intuitive, but I shall remember it!

Comment: @schwobaseggl: I agree that this is a kind of "dangerous syntax". But I did not invent that :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will do what I want but as you say with a weird and unintuitive syntax